# Unable to add a function in MongoDB using Robo Mongo 3T

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, aws-documentdb

Unable to add a function in AWS document DB using Robo Mongo 3T

I Am trying to save the following function. But it is not getting saved. Am not getting any errors also. Any other procedure do we need to follow?

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id : "myAddFunction" ,
     value : function (x, y){ return x + y; }
   }
);
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, Amazon DocumentDB does not support server-side execution of JavaScript code.